# Auto-complete with PyCharm, compiled extensions and 'python_d'

Tags: c++, python, pycharm

I work in a project where we have Python and C++ code. The project uses Visual Studio 2010 and Python 2.7.

While developing, the C++ code is compiled in DEBUG mode, to be able to debug these cases we have **Python compiled "in-house" in debug mode** so we can step into the C++ code and vice-versa.

I want to use *PyCharm* and its auto-complete works correctly if I have my **C++ modules** compiled in *RELEASE*, since these are files named `module.pyd`.

In *DEBUG*, however, they are named `module_d.pyd`, which makes *PyCharm* unable to find the symbols inside my **C++ module**. In *RELEASE* the auto-complete works correctly.

The Python interpreter is set to the **python_d.exe** and the paths are correct.

Is this a known bug in PyCharm or is there any setting I couldn't find that can work?

Comment: Presumably the module_d.pyd gets saved in a debug folder, then you copy it somewhere? Could you copy it to a different folder than where you put the Release version, so you can name it module.pyd instead, and add that folder to the python path?

Comment: That may be a solution, however it doesnt look very nice. But it's a nice workaround

Comment: How about creating a module.py which imports * from module_d?